# What should one return other than success for a custom Action

Tags: vb.net, wix, advanced-installer

I am trying my hand at writing my first Custom Action for an installer (built with [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com)) using the VB Custom Action Project template supplied with the WiX Toolset.  Essentially I just want to test the amount of Ram on a machine to determine which version of a prerequisite ought to be installed if not already present.

What I have so far (in semi pseudo code) is the following;

```
Public Class CustomActions

<CustomAction()> _
Public Shared Function CustomAction1(ByVal session As Session) As ActionResult
    session.Log("Begin CustomAction1")
    If New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory > [ram size here] Then
        Return ActionResult.Success
    Else
        Return ActionResult.SkipRemainingActions
    End If

End Function

End Class
```

What I would like to know is if returning ActionResult.SkipRemainingActions is the correct choice to use if the ram on the machine being tested is less than the result that prompts success.

Comment: what type of prerequisite do you have, it is feature-based or pre-install? If it is pre-install you cannot use custom actions, if it is feature-based have you tried setting the condition directly on the feature in Organization page? (this would result in using the Condition element from AI, as Michael also recommended).

Comment: Bogdan,  Pre requisite is pre install (see my comment under Michael's answer). Your colleague Dan had suggested that a custom action might be the solution to my question (feature requests on the AI forum) but possibly this is not the correct approach. It's not a big deal if this can't be done as I could just install the version of sql according to the os, but as the 64 bit version represents a much larger download I thought it might be good to check and see if the end user would actively gain from having the 64 bit version over the 32 bit one.

Comment: Hi Dom, I'm afraid Dan (my colleague) made a little mistake when formulated his answer on the forums. What he should have said is for you to create your own custom executable (NOT a custom action) written in any language you desire, that checks for that RAM and returns 0 if your RAM size is lower than 4 GB and any other return code if the RAM is higher than 4 GB, and of course in both cases if SQL Server is not already installed. I asked Dan to correct his post, sorry for inconvenience.  http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/prerequisites-edit-search.html

Comment: Many thanks Bogdan, now have it working.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my 2 cents on this... If the condition isn't met, I would terminate the install. If you use what you have then the install will still continue/skip per say and it actually would skip all other conditions. When you use "ActionResult.Failure" this will roll back the installation.

I would use. . .

```
 Return ActionResult.Failure
```

On a side note, I would wrap this up in a Try/Catch and throw a message . . .

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong question to answer (though I agree with the answer of `ActionResult.Failure` for it).

The right question is what is the best way to check for total available memory in Windows Installer. Per the [Windows Installer Property Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905.aspx), the answer is to compare against [PhysicalMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370818.aspx), and the right place to do this is in a [Condition element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/condition.html), not in a custom action.

Comment: Michael, I tend to agree with you on this, but at present that is not an available option with Advanced Installer when installing prerequisites. In essence I'm trying to decide whether it is beneficial to install 64 bit sql server on a 64 os.  From what I have read real gains only come if you have more that 4 gb of ram (the database itself won't be vast) so at present the only way to evaluate this with AI is to use a custom action and use its result to determine the version of sql to load.